# After updating WSL 18.04 LTS' openssl to 1.1.1g, the /usr/local/ssl/bin path is not being appended to user account's $PATH

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssl

Sorry for the long post, but these are the steps I followed and replicated the problem on 1 other WSL 18.04 installation, Windows Version 1903.

**Environment**:

Host: Windows 10 Version 1909

WSL:

```
pacal683@PC-0079241: $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

**Procedure:**

Followed the steps outlined in:
[How to Install the latest OpenSSL version from Source on Linux](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/)
except substituted openssl-1.1.1g.

**Observations:**

After completing the upgrade, the user (pacal683) has the full path as configured and can proceed normally.  After logout, opening the bash terminal again results in an incomplete path i.e., the 
command `/usr/bin/which` fails:

```
pacal683@PC-0079241:~$ which openssl
pacal683@PC-0079241:~$
```

if one `sudo su -` to elevate privileges the command works:

```
root@PC-0079241:~# which openssl
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
root@PC-0079241:~# 
[Text](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

and, while root, `su - pacal683` works:

```
root@PC-0079241:~# su - pacal683
pacal683@PC-0079241:~$ which openssl
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
```

at the user prompt (that doesn't have the correct path), sourcing `/etc/environment` works:

```
pacal683@PC-0079241:~$ source /etc/environment
pacal683@PC-0079241:~$ which openssl
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
```

**Conclusion:**

A couple of solutions come to mind, and work.  I would like the solution to apply to all users:

1. modify pacal683's personal `~/.bashrc` to source `/etc/environment` (not system-wide)
2. add code to `/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh`:

   ```
   # Expand $PATH to include the directory where new openssl path is located:
   openssl_bin_path="/usr/local/ssl/bin"
   if [ -n "${PATH##*${openssl_bin_path}}" -a -n "${PATH##*${openssl_bin_path}:*}" ]; then
       export PATH=$PATH:${openssl_bin_path}
   fi
   ##EOF
   ```
3. Modify the correct system file to enable any user who creates a WSL environment to 
   proceed like they were on a full-blown 18.04 LTS system.

I would prefer #3, who knows the proper place to correct this problem, and possibly push it to WSL distro?